# How do I keep a React Native app running when the screen goes to sleep?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing a timer app. It uses Expo Speech to speak the remaining time. Is it possible to keep the timer running and keep speaking the remaining time after the screen has gone to sleep?

Comment: you need to use 

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I can only see that background-fetch will allow tasks to be scheduled when the app is in the background. It doesn't seem to relate to what is happening in the app.

Comment: I'm going to investigate https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions

Comment: you need to check `Headless JS`